# Another Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery

I have a simple FAQ page and modal that was working on an older version of jQuery, and now updating seems to break it getting a Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error in the console.  I get it in two JS files I have:

[image]

Main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// lightbox ****************************************************************
if (typeof $().simpleLightbox == 'function')
    $('a.buy-now-small').simpleLightbox();
    $('a.buy-now-big').simpleLightbox();

// slideshow ***************************************************************
if (typeof $().slideShow == 'function')
    $('div.visual').slideShow({
        slideEl:'div.images img',       
        linkNext:false,     
        linkPrev:false,     
        linkPause:false,        
        numElementLink:'div.visual-options a',      
        duration:500,
        autoSlideShow:true,     
        switchTime:10000
    });
});
```

FAQ.js

```
    // hover effect
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.faqquestion h3').add('div.faqquestion2 h3').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  });
});

// independently show and hide
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.faqquestion:eq(0) > div').hide();  
  $('div.faqquestion:eq(0) > h3').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
  });
});

// one showing at a time

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.faqquestion:eq(1) > div:gt(0)').hide();  
  $('div.faqquestion:eq(1) > h3').click(function() {
    $(this).next('div:hidden').slideDown('fast')
    .siblings('div:visible').slideUp('fast');
  });
});


//simultaneous showing and hiding

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.faqquestion2:eq(0) > div').hide();
  $('div.faqquestion2:eq(0) > h3').click(function() {
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle('fast')
    .siblings('div:visible').slideUp('fast');
  });
});

//queued showing and hiding
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.faqquestion2:eq(1) > div').hide();  
  $('div.faqquestion2:eq(1) > h3').click(function() {
    var $nextDiv = $(this).next();
    var $visibleSiblings = $nextDiv.siblings('div:visible');

    if ($visibleSiblings.length ) {
      $visibleSiblings.slideUp('fast', function() {
        $nextDiv.slideToggle('fast');
      });
    } else {
       $nextDiv.slideToggle('fast');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the jQuery library has loaded before you attempt to run either of those files?

Comment: ^^ This.  It looks like you're including the jQuery script file *after* the script above.  It needs to be before it.

Comment: I just double checked and moved the scripts into the footer, but jQuery is definitely being called before the scripts.  You can see the example here: http://www.carbonfiberfilm.com/faq/